# Excel VBA code to prompt user to select non-XLSX file, then automatically import/delimit

Tags: vba, excel, button, macros, csv

Relatively new to VBA.

My goal is to have a macro that does the following:
- User clicks on a "Select File" button.  The button generates a prompt for the user to select a non-Excel file (specifically, a *.mrk [library metadata] record).
- Once the user selects the file and clicks Open, the file will be run through the "Import from Text" wizard (when I do this manually, I select "Delimited" in step 1/3.  Then, in step 2/3 I uncheck all the delimiters because I want all the data to appear in one column only.  Maybe there's an easier way to do this?).
- Once the Import Text wizard is complete, the data is placed into one column in a new workbook, and proceeds with the rest of my macro (which cleans up the data).

I know how to set up a button that launches a macro/opens a file, but can't quite figure out how to set up a button that launches text import and then proceeds with running additional macro steps.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: Macro recorder......

Answer (score 0):

That was my first Stack question, didn't realize you had to include code.  I discovered that it was not necessary for me to run a text import on my file: for some reason, if you just have the macro open it, it will be imported into one column.  I don't know, maybe it's just a default setting.

Thanks! I'll be sure to be more thorough next time.